# What IS the opentsdb syntax?

Tags: opentsdb, bosun

Is there a document that actually shows what the OpenTSDB query syntax is meant to be?

I've read http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/query/index.html it talks about the concepts but doesn't actually explain the format.

I'm using bosun, and I see queries like

```
sum:30s-avg-zero:rate{counter}:my.metric.name{tagA=*}{tagB=valueB,tagC=valueC}
```

I can get that `sum` is the aggregation and `my.metric.name` is the metric, and the tags are, well, tags. `30s-avg-zero` LOOKS like down sampling. But I'm just pattern matching things in the query to things in the doc.

There's a lot that I don't understand.
What actually is each element of the `:` separated list? How do I read and understand each query I come across?
Is there a specific ordering to the things in between the `:`?
How are the `{}` used?
etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally managed to find the syntax in the API documentation here: http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/query/index.html